# Laravel: Use "where" in View?

Tags: laravel, collections, view, filtering

Is it possible to use where in a view where I passed a collection toß

For example: I have a collection i pass to my view as `$statuses`.
Inside the view I want to filter the collection for statistic purposes:

Is it possible to do something like this?

```
{{ $statuses->where('category', '=', 'open')->count() }}
```

Comment: yep you can, [read the docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/collections#method-where) although it will strictly works on collection and different with `Builder`'s `Where`.

Comment: Alright, I thought it would work the same as the Builders where(). Just removed the `'='` part and it works. Should check out the docs next time.

Comment: Do you know if it is possible to count in a relationship? Example: `$devices->status->where('category', 'open')->count()` to check how many  devices have the status-category open?

Comment: You'd probably prefer doing this on a Controller anyways. When you need to change this will be quite a headache digging views for that matter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's possible, because there are [`where()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/collections#method-where) and [`count()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/collections#method-count) methods for collections too.

You can see all available methods for collections [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/collections#available-methods)

Comment: Do you know if it is possible to count in a relationship? Example: `$devices->status->where('category', 'open')->count()` to check how many  devices have the status-category open?

Comment: Never tried this. But you can count relations with Eloquent by using `withCount()`